I can't share screen on UBUNTU 22.04.4 LTS with X.Org Nouveau or Nvidia graphics (NVIDIA RTX 4050)
I've be trying a lot share screen using HDMI on my UBUNTU 22.04.4 LTS and I've seen many tutorials about it, but nothing works!
First I will share my notebook configuration:
Dual Boot (windows 11, ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS)
NVIDIA RTX 4050
gcc (Ubuntu 12.3.0-2ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
Now I will share the first method that I have tried to share screen using UBUNTU 22.04.4 LTS.
-Instaling Nvidia driver version 550:
sudo apt-get purge nvidia && sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install gcc-12
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-12 12
gcc --version gcc (Ubuntu 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04) 12.1.0
sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-550
Result: At the first time, I could share screen with othet monitor, but after a few minutes my notebook freezed (stopped).
-Using GNOME GUI Nvidia Installation Method, the nvidia-driver-535 (owned and tested):
Result: The same problem with using Nvidia driver version 550, at the first time, I could share screen with other monitor, but after a few minutes my notebook freezed (stopped).
-Using X.Org.X server - Nouveau display driver:
I tried to disable wayland and enable xorg (x11), but it doesn t works to share screen as well and the wayland couldn t share too.
echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf WaylandEnable=false
sudo reboot
If anyone knows what I might be doing, I would be very grateful. Thanks!
I tried to share screen using HDMI with UBUNTU 22.04.4 LTS with NVIDIA driver version 535, 550 and nouveau. I expected to share screen using HDMI. The results were: freezed notebook and the share screend didn t work.

Nvidia drivers from the Ubuntu repos (or graphics-drivers PPA) should not need the default gcc changed in update-alternatives. Just the presence of the gcc-12 will result it its use.  Joined screens do have problems, but mirroring seems to work fine for me (3080 laptop, Nvidia 545-555 haven't tried 560 yet).
